# How to modify a Cow variable that uses itself in a loop?

Tags: loops, rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I am trying to remove all the parentheses in a string.  Not thinking about it too hard, I just do a simple regexp replace (i.e. the problem in question is not particularly about getting rid of arbitrary levels of nested parentheses, but feel free to suggest a better way of doing that in a comment if you want).

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let input = "Text (with some (nested) parentheses)!";
    let re = Regex::new(r"\([^()]*\)")?;

    let output = re.replace_all(&input, "");
    let output = re.replace_all(&output, "");
    //    let output = re.replace_all(&output, "");
    //    let output = re.replace_all(&output, "");
    //    let output = re.replace_all(&output, "");
    //    let output = re.replace_all(&output, "");
    // ...

    assert_eq!("Text !", output);

    println!("Works!");

    Ok(())
}
```

Because I do not know how nested the parentheses will be, I need to do the replacement in a loop rather than repeating it "just enough times".  Creating a loop, however, creates a new scope and that's where I'm hitting a dead point in the discussion with the borrow checker.

The simplest case that shows what I am trying to do in the loop would be:

```rust
    let mut output = re.replace_all(&input, "");
    while re.is_match(&output) {
        output = re.replace_all(&output, "");
    }
```

However that cannot be done because I am assigning to a borrowed variable:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `output` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         output = re.replace_all(&output, "");
  |         ^^^^^^                  ------- borrow of `output` occurs here
  |         |
  |         assignment to borrowed `output` occurs here
  |         borrow later used here
```

What I would like to do, ideally, is to create new variable binding with the same name, but using `let output =` will shadow the outer variable binding, so the loop would cycle infinitely.

No matter what inner or outer temporary variable I create I cannot make it do what I want.  I also tried using the fact that `re.replace_all()` returns `Cow` and tried using `.to_owned()` and `.to_string()` in a couple of places, but that didn't help either.

Here's a [link to a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14740dae9ef0de022ab8d0555a102293).

Comment: What did you try with `.[in]to_owned()`/`.to_string()`? Something like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1927970778f73b8fc316a4723e7567ee

Comment: @Ry- No. First of all I did not know about `*in*to_owned()`, although it does work with to_string()` as well. Second of all I was most probably already overcomplicating at that point, so I guess I didn't try that (although from looking at it it makes sense, that's what I wanted).

Comment: Check the answer for this as well, it allows you to avoid cloning the string if there were no changes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66714868/how-to-call-regexes-in-a-loop-without-cloning-the-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `re.replace_all()` returns `Cow`

This is the root of the problem. The compiler knows that the return value might reference `output`, but it will also *replace* `output`, causing `output` to be dropped right away. If it allowed this, the reference would point to unallocated memory, leading to memory unsafety.

The solution is to avoid borrowing at all.

> tried using `.to_owned()`

`to_owned` on a `Cow` just returns the same `Cow`. Perhaps you meant `into_owned`?

```
let mut output = re.replace_all(&input, "").into_owned();
while re.is_match(&output) {
    output = re.replace_all(&output, "").into_owned();
}
```

> and `.to_string()` in a couple of places

This works as well:

```
let mut output = re.replace_all(&input, "").to_string();
while re.is_match(&output) {
    output = re.replace_all(&output, "").to_string();
}
```

Comment: I was probably already too sleepy and the workarounds were overcomplicated. I thought I tried what you and @Ry- suggested, byt clearly I didn't. It makes perfect sense as this is what I was trying to tell the compiler I'm trying to achieve, but I was also trying things that I knew can't work. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer forces the data to be copied even if it wasn't modified, defeating the point of using `Cow`

Comment: @intgr the knowledge of "if it wasn't modified" cannot be expressed in Rust's type system, so there's not much to be done there while maintaining memory safety.

Comment: @Shepmaster I just posted a new answer showing how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Shepmaster's answer works, but it's not as efficient as it could be. A subtle property of the `Cow` type is that by inspecting it, we can determine whether the string was modified, and skip work if it wasn't.

Due to constraints of the Rust type system, if the value was **not modified** then `Cow::into_owned()` makes a copy. (`Cow::into_owned()` of a *modified* value does not copy). [(into_owned documentation)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.into_owned)

In your use case, we can detect unmodified `Cow` -- `Cow::Borrowed` -- and skip `into_owned()`.

```rust
    let mut output = /* mutable String */;
    while re.is_match(&output).unwrap() {
        match re.replace_all(&output, "") {
            // Unmodified -- skip copy
            Cow::Borrowed(_) => {}
            // replace_all() returned a new value that we already own
            Cow::Owned(new) => output = new,
        }
    }
```

But we can go further. Calling both `is_match()` and `replace_all()` means the pattern is matched twice. With our new knowledge of `Cow`s, we can optimize that away:

```rust
    let mut output = /* mutable String */;
    // Cow::Owned is returned when the string was modified.
    while let Cow::Owned(new) = re.replace_all(&output, "") {
        output = new;
    }
```

Edit: If your input value is immutable, you can avoid the `.to_string()` copy by making it `Cow` as well:

```rust
    let input = "value";
    let mut output = Cow::from(input);
    while let Cow::Owned(new) = re.replace_all(&output, "") {
        output = Cow::Owned(new);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? [Trying to guess what you mean](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60046c1c5c530f5c225f6ef8bd725c57) yields compilation errors.

Comment: @Shepmaster Ah I assumed `output` is a mutable String, e.g. `let mut output = input.to_string();`. [Here's a working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af88ab76e6ca095d1cf93557eacec324). Tweaked my answer as well.

Comment: So this answer has the same number of string allocations as the existing answer and isn’t more efficient?

Comment: @Shepmaster Obviously it's more efficient because it doesn't need to call `is_match()`. In my personal use case I already had a mutable String, in which case my example does avoid a copy. But if input isn't mutable, you can also avoid that copy by wrapping the intermediate value in `Cow` as well: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=736c5a5d5282ef0dba77caaac614c01e

Comment: You're right though that this assumption wasn't clear from my answer. Edited to clarify that.