# How to call regexes in a loop without cloning the data

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, borrowing

I am writing some code to call an N number of regexes over contents and if possible, I'd like to avoid cloning the strings all the time as not every regex would actually be a match. Is that even possible?
My code where I tried to do is this:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let test = "abcde";
    let regexes = vec![
        (Regex::new("a").unwrap(), "b"),
        (Regex::new("b").unwrap(), "c"),
        (Regex::new("z").unwrap(), "-"),
    ];
    let mut contents = Cow::Borrowed(test);
    
    for (regex, new_value) in regexes {
        contents = regex.replace_all(&contents, new_value);
    }
    println!("{}", contents);
}
```

The expected result there would be `cccde` (if it worked) and two clones. But to make it work, I have to keep cloning on every iteration:

```
fn main() {
    let test = "abcde";
    let regexes = vec![
        (Regex::new("a").unwrap(), "b"),
        (Regex::new("b").unwrap(), "c"),
        (Regex::new("z").unwrap(), "-"),
    ];
    let mut contents = test.to_string();

    for (regex, new_value) in regexes {
        contents = regex.replace_all(&contents, new_value).to_string();
    }
    println!("{}", contents);
}
```

Which then outputs `cccde` but with 3 clones.
Is it possible to avoid it somehow? I know I could call every regex and rebind the return but I do not have control over the amount of regex that could come.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

For those who want to see the real code:
It is doing O(n^2) regexes operations.
It starts here https://github.com/jaysonsantos/there-i-fixed-it/blob/ad214a27606bc595d80bb7c5968d4f80ac032e65/src/plan/executor.rs#L185-L192 and calls this https://github.com/jaysonsantos/there-i-fixed-it/blob/main/src/plan/mod.rs#L107-L115

**EDIT 2**
Here is the new code with the accepted answer https://github.com/jaysonsantos/there-i-fixed-it/commit/a4f5916b3e80749de269efa219b0689cb08551f2

Comment: Is the given example and regular expression simplified or is single character replacement what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify a Cow variable that uses itself in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670511/how-to-modify-a-cow-variable-that-uses-itself-in-a-loop)

Comment: I retracted my close vote, because I found a way I think it can be done without copy. The focus of the proposed duplicate was on how to code it the most simply, but the focus of this question is how to do it without cloning, so I guess they are subtly different.

Comment: @Jason check edit 1, I put the original code there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using a string as the persistent owner of the string as it is being replaced, and on each iteration, checking if the returned `Cow` is owned. If it is owned, you know the replacement was successful, so you assign the string that is owned by the `Cow` into the loop variable.

```
    let mut contents = test.to_owned();
    
    for (regex, new_value) in regexes {
        let new_contents = regex.replace_all(&contents, new_value);
        if let Cow::Owned(new_string) = new_contents {
            contents = new_string;
        }
    }
```

Note that assignment in Rust is by default a 'move' - this means that the value of `new_string` is moved rather than copied into `contents`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66394149240bf13b8cb871d3502e7904)

Comment: Actually, you don't need the swap, using `contents = new_string` (and getting rid of the `mut` in `mut new_string` as well) works, because it just moves the String out of new_contents which is no longer needed, [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21cde9d6f302f05a98e20a868bc459c7).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I will apply the following change on the code I specified on the question (check edit 1)

https://gist.github.com/jaysonsantos/26d78261b3915221c5478bf064f386db

Comment: Thanks @HHK, what was I thinking! This is what comes of switching too rapidly between C++ and Rust mindsets.